# texel density real life like textools 3ds max

Tags: uv

I'm trying to make unwrap, the density of the texel is like in real life. If the mesh that I am unwrapping is 1x2 meters, I want the density of the texels to meet the meter by 1024x1024. How should I do it?
It is a functionality that has the textools plugin of 3ds max, does that exist in blender?
I do not use the addon uv magic since it only applies the scale of the same object.

Comment: Only thing I know is this https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?236631-Addon-Simple-Box-UVW-Map-Modifier

Answer (score 2):

TexTools has been released for Blender and already features Texel Density tools. You can download and read more on [my website](http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/).

[image]

Unlike the 3dsMax version there are now some advanced options on how to apply the UV scale

[image]

Comment: This should be voted as the answer as renderhjs is author of this blender version as well as the 3ds max version of textools.